# Dimension of a complex torus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Conisder $X=\mathbb{C}^g/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a full lattice.

When $g=1$, we get $X$ is homeomorphic to a torus of genus $1$ and that I understand well.

Now, we often say $X$ has dimension $g$ because on $X$ locally we have open subsets of $\mathbb{C}^g$.

What I don't understand is how this topologically corresponds to a genus $g$ torus. In particular, a torus of genus $g$ is a surface so it should have complex dimension $1$ or real dimension $2$.

In Birkenhake's book, we compute the cohomology of $X=\mathbb{C}^g/\Lambda$. $H^0(X,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ as it is connected. Since $\mathbb{C}^g$ is a universal cover for $X$ with fundamental group $\pi_1(X)=\Lambda\cong \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$, $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})=\Lambda$. Now topologically, $\mathbb{C}^g/\Lambda\cong \mathbb{R}^{2g}/\mathbb{Z}^{2g}\cong (S^1)^{2g}$. Using the Kunneth formula recursively, one then shows $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ and the higher cohomolgy groups vanish. This does indeed agree with the singular cohomology of a genus $g$ surface so it does make some sense.

TLDR: How do I visualize the homeomorphism of $\mathbb{C}^g/\Lambda$ to a surface/torus of genus $g>1$? And how do I reconcile the fact that $\mathbb{C}^g/\Lambda$ has dimension $g$ and yet it is topologically a surface?

Comment: If $\Lambda$ is a lattice (which has dimension $0$), then $\Bbb C^g/\Lambda$ has complex dimension $g$ and real dimension $2g$. It is not a surface in general. Also $(S^1)^{2g}$ is an orientable manifold of dimension $2g$ and has nonzero cohomology groups all the way up to degree $2g$.

Comment: The Jacobian of a smooth projective complex curve of genus $g$ is $\mathbb{C}^g/\Lambda$ for some lattice, which is how they arise in the study of Riemann surfaces. It isn't itself a topological surface, unless $g=1$, which should be quite evident from its description. If this is not clear to you then I would recommend that you revise some of the basics of smooth manifolds.

Comment: @pancini Maybe my confusion comes from the word torus. When we describe genus g surfaces, we use the word torus of genus g. But I guess the torus here means a product of $T\cong (S^1)^2$. These two notions agree when $g=1$ but generalize the notion of a torus in different ways.

Comment: @daruma Topologically, an orientable surface of genus $g$ is homeomorphic to the connected sum of the torus $(S^1)^2$ with itself $g$ times. This is different from the product of $(S^1)^2$ with itself $g$ times, which would be a real manifold of dimension $2g$, that is homeomorphic to a complex torus $\mathbb C^g / \Lambda$ of _complex dimension_ $g$. Maybe that's where the confusion comes from?

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon That makes sense. I think my confusion arose from the fact that genus g surfaces are also sometimes referred to as g-torus.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon your comment looks like an answer to me